# Obtaining the expression for nth prime from PNT with remainder

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory

Given the Prime number theorem with the error term : $π(x) = li(x) + O(x.e^{−c\sqrt{log(x)}}))$ , how do you go about obtaining an expression for the nth prime?

Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

If we take $x=p_n$ in the prime number theorem we obtain $n=\pi(p_n)=\frac{p_n}{\log(p_n)}+$ O-Term, so that $p_n=n\log(n)+$ O-Term. For a discussion see [Estimate of $n$th prime](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/606955/estimate-of-nth-prime). For better estimates on the $n$-prime see the article by [Dusard](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.364.882&rep=rep1&type=pdf).

Comment: Wouldn't that be n=π(p_n)=li(p_n)+ O-Term?  how do i go from there?

Comment: We have $li(p_n)=p_n/\log(p_n)+$ O-Term, so this goes as before.